# Include comma in a field value of csv (delimeter as comma) in java

Tags: java, string, csv, delimiter

I want to create a csv file in which delimiter is comma seperated.While csv is read it make s5 string in comma seperation. Want to keep s5 string in single column.

```
   String s1="quick";
   String s2="brown";
   String s3="fox";
   String s4="jump";
   String s5="over,the,lazy,dog";


  String csvRecord = String.format("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s", s1,s2,s3,s4,s5);
```

Can anybody help me out, as i am new to strings.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add them in a double string.

Try this:

```
String s5="\"over,the,lazy,dog\"";
```

Comment: Checking the Wikipedia page for CSV ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Example ) shows that it's commonplace to quote strings that include commas. So this is a proper solution.

Comment: Not at all an appropriate solution - if a value has a quote character it needs to be properly escaped.

Answer (score 0):

To include a delimiter in the data, you have to enclose the field with double quotes in the resulting csv:

```
quick,brown,fox,jump,"over,the,lazy,dog"
```

If there are double quotes inside some fields those have to be escaped:

```
123,"24"" monitor, Samsung",456  // Windows style
123,"24\" monitor",456           // Linux style
```

You don't have to quote all the fields, only those containing a delimiter or a double quote (or a newline).

See [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) for more details on the csv common format.

Answer (score 0):

Just as other answers mentioned, you have to actually consider many special cases and the most typical two special cases will be: comma and double quotes.

As Chewtoy enclosed, the [CSV wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Example) has clearly specify the format as:

[image]

```
Year,Make,Model,Description,Price
1997,Ford,E350,"ac, abs, moon",3000.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition""","",4900.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition, Very Large""",,5000.00
1996,Jeep,Grand Cherokee,"MUST SELL!
air, moon roof, loaded",4799.00
```

To handle these two cases, you can try something as:

```
public class CsvAddComma {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("quick");
        list.add("over,the,lazy,dog");
        list.add("Venture \"Extended Edition, Very Large\"");
        list.stream()
                .map(s -> convertToCsvFormat(s))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static String convertToCsvFormat(String input) {
        if (input.contains("\"")) {
            input = input.replaceAll("\"", "\"\"");
        }
        if (input.contains(",")) {
            input = String.format("\"%s\"", input);
        }
        return input;
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
quick
"over,the,lazy,dog"
"Venture ""Extended Edition, Very Large"""
```

As for other special cases, you need to handle them according to your current case. Perhaps they can be ignored, perhaps not.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are toying with some assignment you absolutely NEED a CSV library to handle this for you. You also need to care about line endings and other quotes inside the values, not only the delimiter

Try the following code with [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial):

```
CsvWriterSettings settings = new CsvWriterSettings();
CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(settings);
String result = writer.writeRowToString(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5);
```

Hope this helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library. It's open source and free (Apache 2.0 license)